# Excessive queries in Laravel 4.2. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

So, I have this relationship:

```
public function publishedAlbums()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Album')->where('is_published', true)->has('photos');
}

public function getPhotoCountAttribute()
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($this->publishedAlbums as $album)
    {
        $count += $album->photos->count();
    }
    return $count;
}
```

It gets an accurate count, but it results in 7 queries for my 7 albums, even though I'm doing eager loading with has('Photos'). My understanding is that if I do this right, there only needs to be one query. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [`with`](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_with) not [`has`](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_has) for [eager-loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading).

`has` checks to make sure that a model has at least X number of a related model associated.

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression that has did both but it does not.